# Removing superfluos layers from DXFwrite

Tags: python, cad, dxf

I use the python package DXFwrite to construct solar cell grids. Unfortunately my simulation program is confused by additional layers introduced by DXFwrite. Their names are:

- DIMENSIONS
- TABLECONTENT
- TABLEGRID
- TABLEBACKGROUND
- VIEWPORTS

Is there a simple way to prevent DXFwrite from creating these layers? I have not found any command to remove layers.

Best Regards,

Thorsten Rissom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after skimming through the [source](https://github.com/mozman/dxfwrite/blob/master/dxfwrite/tables.py) - there is a possibility.

DXFEngine.layers is an intern _Table structure, which has a clear() function.
Haven't tested for unwanted side-effects but you can do the following:

```
from dxfwrite import DXFEngine as mydxfwrite
mydxfdrawing = mydxfwrite.drawing('Filename.dxf')
mydxfdrawing.layers.clear() #clears the layers
mydxfdrawing.add_layer("JUSTASINGLELAYER",color=1) #add your layer with for example a specific color
mydxfdrawing.save()
```

[LibreCad](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html), however, still shows a layer called "0" apart from the layer "JUSTASINGLELAYER".

Best wishes,
Martin

Comment: That works as well. It does however not remove the layer "VIEWPORTS". In the end I followed the second alternative in the answer from @mozman. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

No there is no method to delete layers and you can not prevent dxfwrite from creating this layers.

Alternative 1:

Use ezdxf (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezdxf/), but there are also some predefined layers (DEFPOINTS, VIEW_PORT), but you can delete entries from the
layer table: `dwg.layers.remove('layername')`, this removes only the layer table entry, a layer is only deleted if not entity references this layer. And maybe there are some unexpected side effects.

Alternative 2:

Use ezdxf.r12writer: this module can be used without the ezdxf package, just copy r12writer.py into your project. The module writes very basic DXF12 files, see docs: http://pythonhosted.org/ezdxf/r12writer.html.

- Supported entities: LINE, CIRCLE, ARC, TEXT, POINT, SOLID, 3DFACE and POLYLINE
- Block references are not supported!
- additional advantage: r12writer is very fast